# GridSplitter behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

I am trying to add columns and gridsplitters to a grid, but can't get the exact behavior.
After the user specifies where he wants a vertical splitter to appear:

```
             // Get current Col0 width, size new col and existing Col0
            double col0Width = LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth;
            double newCol0Width = col0Width - 5 - pt.X;
            LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(newCol0Width);

            // New Column 0
            var c = new ColumnDefinition();
            c.Width = new GridLength(pt.X);
            LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(0, c);// Attach GridSplitter to left edge of existing first column
            var gss = new GridSplitter();
            gss.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateBlue);
            gss.Width = 5;    gss.Cursor = Cursors.ScrollWE;
            gss.ResizeBehavior = GridResizeBehavior.BasedOnAlignment;
            gss.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(gss);
            // Add to current left-most colunn
            Grid.SetColumn(gss, 0);

            // Create new column, insert
            // New Column 0
            var c = new ColumnDefinition();
            c.Width = new GridLength(pt.X);
            LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(0, c);  

            // Move existing content from Col 0 to new Col 1.
```

I can repeat this and create an arbitrary number of vertical splitters.

The required resize behavior: moving a splitter resizes only the columns immed. to the left and right of the splitter.
The current resize behavior: moving a splitter treats everything to the right of the splitter as one object, expanding or shrinking the column to the left of the splitter, while moving everything to the right.  That is, if there are 3 columns, moving the left-most splitter appears to push col 2 to the right and shrinking col 3, without resizing col 2.
(I hope I explained that clearly enough.)
I have tried putting the GridSplitters in their own columns, and tried various GridResizeBehaviors, but haven't found the correct combination.

Any tips would be appreciated....

And a related question:  In an event handler for GridSplitter's OnDragDelta, is there a way to stop the splitter from traveling any further in a certain direction?  I would like to prevent them from shrinking the right-most column below a certain width, while allowing them to move the splitter back to the left.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is assigning widths to columns.  I want to create the new column w/i the limits of the current column 0.  However, to get the gridsplitters to work as desired, it seems I'll have to calculate all the new column widths and set them to appropriate '*' sizes.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggested, it looks like the columns need to be '*' sized.
So, after adding the new column and splitter, I fixed up the widths like this (first clumsy cut at solution):

```
 // Get all col widths, set appropriate '*' sizes.
        foreach (ColumnDefinition col in LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions)
        {
            colWidths.Add(col.Width);
            total += col.Width.Value;

            Debug.WriteLine($" Width : {col.Width}");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"{total}");

        for (int i = 0; i < LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
        {
            double d = colWidths[i].Value;
            double ratio = d / total;
            int ii = (int) (ratio * 100);

            LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions[i].Width = new GridLength(ii, GridUnitType.Star);
        }
```